# Can`t print request response with Python

Tags: python, encoding

Stack Overfellas! Im using Python 2.7.13 with requests library and I want to print the response of the request im sending to site:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("url")
print r.text
```

But `print r.text` rasises an error: `'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 16311: character maps to <undefined>`

I've searched this error and only advice I get is to define encoding prematurely by using `r.encode`:

```
r.encode = "utf-8"
r.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

But it didn't help, `r.text` raises the same error.

Comment: I believe that problem is in the url being a string `'url'`, instead of actual url

Comment: What is response encoding?

Comment: It is utf-8 already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting `text` to the newly encoded text?

```
text = u'\u2018'
text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print text
```